# Is it possible to restrict or change android immersive (immersive-sticky) mode swipe detection area?

Tags: android, libgdx, swipe

I am making a **Libgdx** game on my android device, which uses finger swipes a lot. I want it to be in fullscreen mode with **navigation bar hidden**, that's why I set the useImmersiveMode flag found in AndroidApplicationConfiguration class. Unfortunately, navigation bar pops up every time I try to drag an item from the inventory, which is located on the right side of the screen.

I have tried many options with not satisfying results.

1. Immersive sticky mode works perfectly, but it results in navigation bar appearing all the time, which is very annoying.
2. Immersive non-sticky mode has similar flaws and I didn't find a way to restrict navigation bar swipe area.
3. I tried to hide system UI as fast as possible everytime the bar appeared, but it seems that it cannot be hidden until it reaches to the end.
4. I tried to set SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION flag and handle touch and drag events to prevent bar from appearing, but in some way android system always knows when the screen was touched.

All known tutorials including the one present here (https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) and here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBi8fjv90E4) didn't solve that problem for me.

**What I want to achieve** is to have fullscreen mode, where navigation and status bars appear only if I swipe from top of the screen towards bottom.

I tried to figure it out for over dozen of hours, but now I am completely powerless.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Were you ever able to get some progress with this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Sadly, I think they are quite devoted in the matter of preserving standard ui behaviour across all android versions :(